# Какую базу данных следует выбрать для хранения большого количества тестовых данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Речь идёт о гигабайтах, а возможно, и о терабайтах тестовых данных. Причём по всем по ним нужен полнотекстовый поиск.

Comment: Вы уж все-таки определитесь,, о чем идет речь, какие точные требования к сервису, а там уже будет понятней, с чего начинать. Посоветовать БД на терабайты просто так нельзя. Дайте SLA.

Comment: А почему в ключевых словах MySQL? Вы будете работать с ней? База данных обязательно должна быть реляционной или допускается NoSQL-решение?

Comment: @Etki таких проектов пока нет поэтому я не могу сказать что то вроде "мне нужна база для хранения заказов интернет магазина". это текстовые данные, их очень очень много и по ним нужно быстро искать.

Comment: @cheops просто с MySQL я немного умею работать, но у меня возникают сомнения в том, что она будет пригодна для таких огромных масштабов данных. Про NoSQL практически ничего не знаю, но спасибо за наводку.

Comment: если у вас не алиэкспресс, то ни о каких гигабайтах речи не идет. что с базой-то делать планируете?